# How to order files based on the file name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reading from a directory in nodejs and listing files. Files in the directory:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  35 23 Aug 21:34 0.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  33 23 Aug 21:34 1.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  41 23 Aug 21:34 2.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  56 23 Aug 21:34 3.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  31 23 Aug 21:34 4.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  28 23 Aug 21:34 5.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 6.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 7.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 8.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 9.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 10.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 11.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 12.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 13.js
-rw-r--r--  1 coding  staff  32 23 Aug 21:34 14.js
```

Currently, I am reading files using the call `fs.readdirSync` but not able to read it according to the file number i.e. I want to read in the numeric order i.e. I want to process in file order of `1, 2, 3, 4, .....,9, 10, 11, ....`.

Is there a way to sort the files according to the file number that appears before the ".js" extension?

Comment: IMO, `ARRAY#sort` should help!

Comment: thats gives `1, 10, 2, .....`?

Comment: Have you looked into anything with `Array.prototype.sort`?

Comment: @Exploring - Do not consider the entire file name, consider just a number.

Comment: @Exploring if it gave that, that might be of comparing string, so to sort numerically, you should parse to number first, using `Number()`, or just  `+` prefix

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort file name based on numeric property.

```
files.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are all just numbers, and you have an array with strings in the format `###.js`, you can sort it with:

```
input.sort((a,b) => {
   return a.split('.')[0] - b.split('.')[0]
});
```

Or

```
input.sort((a,b) => {
   return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10)
});
```

Comment: all the file names are with numbers in increasing order 1.js, 2.js, ......99.js, 100,js, .....

Comment: can it handle if there are millions of files? I think it should work as nodejs int range is very large.

Comment: Since they are numeric names can simplify down to `return a.split('.')[0] - b.split('.')[0]`

Comment: `parseInt` will stop at invalid characters, so `input.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10))` is a potential simplification.

Comment: @Evert I am not sure whether a.split('.')[0] will work. It would return a string and not number - right? I think we have to manually parse it using `parseInt`. So I think the previous code that you pasted was more correct.

Comment: very interesting finding, parseInt actually works with any name as long as it starts with a number, like parseInt('10_ast.json') with give `10`.

Comment: @Exploring it will work, because `"10" - "4"` works in javascript and results in `6`.

Comment: @Ry- added your suggestion as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with vanilla JS after having read the files:

```js
const files = fs.readdirSync('pathToFolder');
const sortedFiles = files.sort((fileNameA, fileNameB) => {
  // Note: this line assumes all the files are in the format of <number>.js
  const fileANumber = Number(fileNameA.split('.js')[0]);
  const fileBNumber = Number(fileNameB.split('.js')[0]);

  return fileANumber = fileBNumber;
});

sortedFiles.forEach((fileName) => {
 // doSomething();
});
```